# Laravel Call to a member function parameters() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, logging

Am having this problem and not able to find any solution for that, please help:

exception `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException` with message `Call to a member function parameters() on a non-object`

The error is on the: "$route->parameters()"

```
 protected function substituteBindings($route)
    {
            foreach ($route->parameters() as $key => $value)
            {
                    if (isset($this->binders[$key]))
                    {
                            $route->setParameter($key, $this->performBinding($key, $value, $route));
                    }
            }

            return $route;
    }
```

Am receiving tons of this same error anytime i use the app. any suggestions?

Comment: $route is not an object

Answer (score 4):

I think you upgrade your Laravel! I dont know why, but if you remove `SubstituteBindings` from `$middleware` and `web` at `app\Http\Middlewares\Kernel.php` everything will works!

Answer (score 3):

By fallowing Laravel documentation I have added SubtituteBindings to $middleware array. 
But I needed to add it to $middlewareGroups array. 
Documentation is a bit not clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from Laravel 4.2 to 5.3 .. :)
I got this error:

```
FatalErrorException in Router.php line 781: Call to a member function parameters() on null
```

Similar with the main error. Reason is typo and/or misconfiguration (after/before upgrading), replace the **$middlewareGroups ** lines with as:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

That's it!